# calling system("command") from signal handler

Tags: command, signals

In a signal handler, I saw `system()` used to invoke some shell commands, like

```
void
sig_handler(int signum) {
   system("command1");
   system("command2");
   system("command3");
   signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
}
```

Is it safe to make calls in this way, in a signal handler (bound to `SIGSEGV`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGBUS` ...), and then invoke the default handler ?
or does it depend on the *commands* being invoked ?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 2):

The `system` call is not documented to be safe to call from a signal handler (or at least I cannot find such a documentation), so I'd conclude that this code is not guaranteed to be safe.

However, `fork`, `execve`, `waitpid` and `signal` are all documented to be safe, so I think the *functionality* of that code should be safe in principle, if implemented using `fork`/`exec`/`waitpid` instead of `system`.